Kali Linux Broadcom BCM43142 Not Working
I recently took an old Toshiba laptop and loaded Kali Linux onto it. Everything is working great with one exception--the wireless adapter. When originally setting up the new OS, it failed several times when trying to configure the wireless network, however I was able to skip over this part. When in Kali, there is no option for a wireless adapter anywhere. I used lspci to check if the wireless adapter was recognized and one showed up: a Broadcom BCM43142. I was able to connect the laptop with ethernet to connect to the internet and try some troubleshooting I found on the web. However, many of these methods are for older versions (about 8 years old). The version of Kali that I am running is 2024.1. I am assuming that the issue I am encountering is related to a driver missing for this specific adapter, however I am unsure the best way to get these and set up the wireless to let Kali use the adapter and access WiFi.
I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Kali is for use by experts that do not have to ask your question ... it is designed to not connect to anything by default ... instead, run a user friendly Linux distribution, such as Ubuntu or Mint etc

Hello Linux Community!
After some additional research and help from friendly Kali users, I have successfully connected my Kali machine to the wireless network. I was missing wl/broadcom-sta-dkms which is the proprietary Broadcom wireless driver for the BCM43142 card. I found the information at wiki.debian.org/wl very helpful in this process.
In order to get Kali to be able to use the wireless adapter here are the steps that I followed:
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic broadcom-sta-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure broadcom-sta-dkms
sudo apt-get install wl
sudo modprobe wl
sudo reboot

This process installed the driver/dependencies and and loaded them to be used. After this was done, the device needed to be restarted to implement the changes.
This fix was surprisingly simple and I appreciate those who have helped me. To those who are discouraged and considering giving up... don't!!! While some users can be unhelpful and discouraging, others can show you just what you need to get things done!
